# Custom post permalink redirects to homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

Custom post permalink redirects to homepage.

When clicking the permalink from admin the url redirects to homepage .

Also single-{post type}.php also not working.

Please help out !

```
function fovit_events_post_type() 
{
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => __('Events','mfn-opts'),
        'singular_name'         => __('Events','mfn-opts'),
        'add_new'               => __('Add New','mfn-opts'),
        'add_new_item'          => __('Add New Events','mfn-opts'),
        'edit_item'             => __('Edit Events','mfn-opts'),
        'new_item'              => __('New Events','mfn-opts'),
        'view_item'             => __('View Events','mfn-opts'),
        'search_items'          => __('Search Events','mfn-opts'),
        'not_found'             => __('No events found','mfn-opts'),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __('No events found in Trash','mfn-opts'), 
        'parent_item_colon'     => ''
      );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-controls-volumeon',
        'public'                => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'show_ui'               => true, 
        'query_var'             => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'menu_position'         => null,
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => $events_item_slug, 'with_front'=>true ),
        'supports'              => array( 'title','thumbnail','editor' ),
    ); 

    register_post_type( 'events', $args );

    register_taxonomy( 'events-types', 'events', array(
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'label'                 =>  __('Event categories','mfn-opts'),
        'singular_label'        =>  __('Event category','mfn-opts'),
        /*'rewrite'             => true,*/
        'query_var'             => true
    ));
}
}
add_action( 'init', 'fovit_events_post_type' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Setting -> permalink and re-update struct permalink.